# Delayed boot with fscryptctl and kernel file system encryption

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, disk-encryption, modprobe

I've enabled disk encryption using fscryptctl for part of my buildroot build which is run on an TI AM335x. Once fscryptctl has inserted the key into the file system, when the file system is manipulated, which happens during boot. The boot is delayed, with the following message;

```
[   11.830969] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cts(cbc(aes)), throttling...
[   16.882010] request_module: modprobe crypto-cts(cbc(aes)) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   16.894836] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cts(cbc(aes))-all, throttling...
[   21.921400] request_module: modprobe crypto-cts(cbc(aes))-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   21.951692] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cbc(aes), throttling...
[   27.041390] request_module: modprobe crypto-cbc(aes) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   27.053529] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cbc(aes)-all, throttling...
[   32.081413] request_module: modprobe crypto-cbc(aes)-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   32.112925] fscrypt: AES-256-CTS-CBC using implementation "cts(cbc(aes-generic))"
[   32.157809] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-xts(aes), throttling...
[   37.201404] request_module: modprobe crypto-xts(aes) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   37.213554] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-xts(aes)-all, throttling...
[   42.241409] request_module: modprobe crypto-xts(aes)-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   42.271482] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-aes, throttling...
[   47.361399] request_module: modprobe crypto-aes cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   47.373078] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-aes-all, throttling...
[   52.401501] request_module: modprobe crypto-aes-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 100 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   52.413610] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module cryptomgr, throttling...
[   57.441884] request_module: modprobe cryptomgr cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   57.453523] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-ecb(aes), throttling...
[   62.481629] request_module: modprobe crypto-ecb(aes) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   62.493723] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-ecb(aes)-all, throttling...
[   67.521683] request_module: modprobe crypto-ecb(aes)-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   67.536046] fscrypt: AES-256-XTS using implementation "xts(ecb(aes-generic))"
```

I've managed to reduce this time by changing the AES modules to be compiled into the kernel. Now the boot log has this in it;

```
[   10.542972] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cts(cbc(aes)), throttling...
[   15.604200] request_module: modprobe crypto-cts(cbc(aes)) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   15.617017] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cts(cbc(aes))-all, throttling...
[   20.643736] request_module: modprobe crypto-cts(cbc(aes))-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   20.674918] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cryptd(__cbc-aes-neonbs), throttling...
[   25.763747] request_module: modprobe crypto-cryptd(__cbc-aes-neonbs) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   25.777340] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cryptd(__cbc-aes-neonbs)-all, throttling...
[   30.803742] request_module: modprobe crypto-cryptd(__cbc-aes-neonbs)-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   30.834599] fscrypt: AES-256-CTS-CBC using implementation "cts(cbc-aes-neonbs)"
[   30.890095] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cryptd(__xts-aes-neonbs), throttling...
[   35.923747] request_module: modprobe crypto-cryptd(__xts-aes-neonbs) cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   35.937348] request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module crypto-cryptd(__xts-aes-neonbs)-all, throttling...
[   40.963785] request_module: modprobe crypto-cryptd(__xts-aes-neonbs)-all cannot be processed, kmod busy with 50 threads for more than 5 seconds now
[   40.994725] fscrypt: AES-256-XTS using implementation "xts-aes-neonbs"`
```

So I've reduced the issue by 27 seconds, but I haven't quite solved the issue as it's still taking 30 seconds. I've tried patching the kernel so max_modprobes is 100, and it doesn't appear to have any effect.

I've tried changing the linux configuration so that `crypto-cryptd` and `crypto-cts` is compiled in the kernel too, rather than as a module (`CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRYPTD=y` and `CONFIG_CRYPTO_CTS=y`). It hasn't had any noticeable effect on the boot times and I'm still getting the messages in the second boot log snippet.

It looks like it's trying to load a few different modules, before it settles on the ARM specific implementations. Is there a way of giving the system a hint as to which modules will need loading, rather than letting it decide for itself, potentially avoiding the 30 second wait? Or is there another way of fixing this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Comment: It looks like `fscrypt_get_encryption_info` is called for a lot of inodes on disk, which is why I'm getting the `max_modprobes` messages.

Comment: And it's getting stuck in `request_module(...)` which appears to be a part of kmod.

Comment: Ah, and the call is coming from `ext4_fname_prepare_lookup(...)` within the ext4.h header. I think I should probably continue to look for ways that `request_module` could be optimised.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue, by commenting out the `request_module` call. Any call to `request_module` is going to fail when the modules are builtin, but changing them to be modules doesn't help either.

Comment: It appears that modules like `crypto-cts(cbc(aes))` are always builtin.